# JBOSS AS 7 server is not starting

Tags: java, jboss, environment-variables, jboss7.x

I am trying to start JBOSS Appication Server 7. But its showing some error.

I searched on google for that and 90% people are saying that you have problem in your

JAVA_HOME environment variable. I am sharing some screen shots.One more important thing

that i can start Tomcat server without any issues. that means my java_home is set ok.

But when i am clicking on standalone.bat its showing me Screen Like in Second screen shot.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You show everything other than the error that you're observing.  Pretty tough for anyone to be able to help you!

Comment: Please update your Java version - 6u07 is ancient and insecure!

Comment: So is Jboss 7.0 for that matter, its only an alpha version of the enterprise release built for testing the AS. You should download the tag of JBoss 7.2 and build that (using the build.sh included) so you get a far more secure version; literally more than a thousand bugs have been fixed since the pre-built community releases you can download - which are all alpha and beta versions regardless of the "final" tag they put in the filename.